# Android : null returned by createVideoThumbnail

Tags: android

I am using ThumbnailUtils to create a video thumbnail. This is the code :

```
bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( uri.getPath() , MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND );
```

I am selecting a video from gallery but thumbnail returned is null. Uri in this case is content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A10826 .

What could be wrong?